# Unexpected class property behavior in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am making a game with TypeScript and I was making a class for the player but now I get this error upon adding properties:

```
Property 'playerInformation' does not exist on type 'Player'
```

Code:

```js
export default class Player {
    constructor(playerInformation={}) {
        
        console.log("Player initalized");
        this.playerInformation = playerInformation
    }

    test() {
        console.log(this.playerInformation);
    }
}
```

Anyone know a fix?

Comment: Define the property? Or do it in one go, with a parameter property. Read [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html).

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh yeah I forgot to do that

Comment: Don't write "SOLVED" in the title, because this doesn't help in any way. Either accept an answer that solved your problem. Write your own if there isn't (already) one that helped and accept that. Or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have fixed the issue. Realized I forgot to define the property on the class as so:

```
    playerInformation: object;
    constructor(playerInformation={}) {
        
        console.log("Player initalized");
        this.playerInformation = playerInformation
    }

    test() {
        console.log(this.playerInformation);
    }
}
```